# Changing LineChart's line color dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm currently building a patient tracking application where patients can save their blood pressures any time they measure. And from the data they enter, a graph is built. On the same graph, I'm showing both diastole and systole. What I want is to change graph line's color if it falls below or goes beyond a threshold value. For ex. for diastole if it falls below 60 or goes beyond 100, I want the line to turn red from that point until a new data is entered which is between 60-100.

Sorry if the code is hard to read but it's still in the prototype phase. Here is my current code:

```
class Graph extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GraphState createState() => _GraphState();
}

class _GraphState extends State<Graph> {
  final kTansiyon = [80, 70, 63, 76, 82, 90];
  final kTimes = [7, 13.6, 15.8, 17, 20, 22];
  final bTansiyon = [121, 136, 117, 120, 110, 112];
  final bTimes = [10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22];

  List<FlSpot> createSpots(List<int> tansiyon, List<int> times) {
    List<FlSpot> retVal = [];
    if (tansiyon.length != times.length) {
      return null;
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < tansiyon.length; i++) {
        retVal.add(FlSpot(
            times.elementAt(i).toDouble(), tansiyon.elementAt(i).toDouble()));
      }
    }
    return retVal;
  }

  List<Color> kgradientColors = [
    const Color(0xff23b6e6),
  ];

  List<Color> bgradientColors = [Colors.grey];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LineChart(
      LineChartData(
          minX: 0,
          minY: 0,
          maxX: 24,
          maxY: 150,
          titlesData: FlTitlesData(
            show: true,
            bottomTitles: SideTitles(
                showTitles: true,
                reservedSize: 35,
                getTextStyles: (BuildContext context, value) => const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 10),
                getTitles: (value) {
                  switch (value.toInt()) {
                    case 4:
                      return '4:00';
                      break;
                    case 8:
                      return '8:00';
                      break;
                    case 12:
                      return '12:00';
                      break;
                    case 16:
                      return '16:00';
                      break;
                    case 20:
                      return '20:00';
                      break;
                    case 24:
                      return '00:00';
                      break;
                  }
                  return '';
                }),
            leftTitles: SideTitles(
              showTitles: true,
              getTextStyles: (BuildContext context, value) => const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 10),
              getTitles: (value) {
                if (value % 10 == 0) {
                  return '${value.toInt()}';
                }
                return '';
              },
            ),
          ),
          gridData: FlGridData(
            show: false,
            drawVerticalLine: true,
            getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
              return FlLine(
                color: const Color(0xff37434d),
                strokeWidth: 1,
              );
            },
            getDrawingVerticalLine: (value) {
              return FlLine(
                color: const Color(0xff37434d),
                strokeWidth: 1,
              );
            },
          ),
          borderData: FlBorderData(
            show: true,
            border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xff37434d), width: 1),
          ),
          lineBarsData: [
            LineChartBarData(
              spots: [
                FlSpot(9, 80),
                FlSpot(12, 77),
                FlSpot(15, 80),
                FlSpot(18, 90),
                FlSpot(21, 62),
              ],
              isCurved: true,
              colors: kgradientColors,
              barWidth: 5,
              isStrokeCapRound: true,
              dotData: FlDotData(
                show: false,
              ),
              belowBarData: BarAreaData(
                show: true,
                colors: kgradientColors
                    .map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
            LineChartBarData(
              spots: [
                FlSpot(7, 120),
                FlSpot(9, 130),
                FlSpot(11, 116),
                FlSpot(22, 128),
                FlSpot(23, 123),
              ],
              isCurved: true,
              colors: bgradientColors,
              barWidth: 5,
              isStrokeCapRound: true,
              dotData: FlDotData(
                show: false,
              ),
              belowBarData: BarAreaData(
                show: true,
                colors: bgradientColors
                    .map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
            LineChartBarData(
              spots: [],
              isCurved: true,
              colors: bgradientColors,
              barWidth: 5,
              isStrokeCapRound: true,
              dotData: FlDotData(
                show: false,
              ),
              belowBarData: BarAreaData(
                show: true,
                colors: bgradientColors
                    .map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            )
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how it looks at the moment:

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TJU5.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the current code for one of the lines:

```dart
LineChartBarData(
  spots: [
    FlSpot(9, 80),
    FlSpot(12, 77),
    FlSpot(15, 80),
    FlSpot(18, 90),
    FlSpot(21, 62),
  ],
  isCurved: true,
  colors: kgradientColors,
  barWidth: 5,
  isStrokeCapRound: true,
  dotData: FlDotData(
    show: false,
  ),
  belowBarData: BarAreaData(
    show: true,
    colors: kgradientColors
      .map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3))
         .toList(),
  ),
),
```

The first thing you would need to do is to factor out the placeholder values for the spots into a variable we can reference in order to determine what line color to use.

```dart
List<FlSpot> spots = [
  FlSpot(9, 80),
  FlSpot(12, 77),
  FlSpot(15, 80),
  FlSpot(18, 90),
  FlSpot(21, 62),
];
```

Then instead of `kgradientColors` lets define two different color sets, one to use for a red line and one for the blue line.

```dart
List<Color> redColors = [
  Colors.red,
];

List<Color> blueColors = [
  Colors.blue,
];
```

Then we can define a helper function that picks the correct color set based on if the last value in spots is between 60 and 100:

```dart
List<Color> get lineColors => spots.last.y <= 100 && spots.last.y >= 60
    ? blueColors
    : redColors;
```

Then use it in the `LineChartBarData`:

```dart
LineChartBarData(
  spots: spots,
  isCurved: true,
  colors: lineColors,
  barWidth: 5,
  isStrokeCapRound: true,
  dotData: FlDotData(
    show: false,
  ),
  belowBarData: BarAreaData(
    show: true,
    colors: lineColors
      .map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3))
         .toList(),
  ),
),
```

Comment: This code snippet changes the color below the lines. I want to change the colors of the lines themselves.

Comment: within the `LineChartBarData` there are two places where the `colors` are set, the first controls the line color itself, and the second controls the below the lines color.

Comment: I will try ASAP and let you know, thanks a lot for your efforts chief :)

Comment: I deleted the belowBarData part and used colors part of LineChartBarData but it still doesn't work. The line is always blue.

Comment: I realized that I may have been misleading you. What I want is to change the color of the part that exceeds the threshold value. For ex. the line is blue at 87 and the next value 117. The part that is above 100 of the curve that connects 87 and 117 is red. The next value is 90. The curve is still red until 100 and between 100-90 it goes back to blue again.